# Crear Red Neuronal Siamesa en Python con Keras

Tags: python, keras

Quiero crear una red neuronal siamesa en python con un esquema parecido a este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seria pasarle dos imágenes distintas a dos redes las cuales compartirian pesos, y luego estas se "concatenarian" para pasar varias capas más para posteriormente producir una salida.

En principio, tengo este código que he podido sacar más o menos de la documentación de Keras:

```
def create_base_network(input_shape):
    input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Flatten()(input)
    x = Conv2D(96, (11, 11), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)
        #LRN1
    x = Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool2')(x)
        #LRN2
    x = Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool3')(x)

    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    return Model(input, x)
```

(Las capas LRN no sé como ponerlas en Keras, esto sería otra de las dudas)
También quiero saber como interpretar la nomenclatura del esquema de cara al código. Es decir, que significa, por ejemplo que una capa convolucional sea (3x3, 256,2)

Esto sería la red base, esta debe llamarse dos veces, cada una con una imagen y compartir los pesos entre ellas.

A continuacion me gustaría saber como concatenar dos modelos de esta red, para seguir añadiendo capas. Por el momento solo tengo esta duda, conforme me vayan surgiendo más os iré contando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver, no soy experto empalmando redes, pero diría que debes definir la arquitectura antes de compilar el modelo.

Como primer consejo no empieces con Flatten. La idea de las redes convolucionales es empezar con filtros aprendidos que obtengan las características elementales de la imagen antes de embeberlas en un vector (lo que hace la capa Flatten) dónde ya no tengamos pixeles, sino características obtenidas de los filtros.

La cosa sería empezar con Convs, polling, padding, etc para luego meterle un Flatten y unas capas Dense que permitar discriminar el resultado final.

Un saludo y espero que sirva de ayuda